# Detectar estado de Caps Lock en c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un campo contraseña en un Windows Form de `C#` y necesito mostrar al usuario una alerta si la función **CapsLock** está activada.

¿ Cómo puedo detectar si la función **CapsLock** está activada ?

Comment: En estos momentos no tengo acceso a otras páginas, solo stackoverflow debido a la restricción de conexión en mi trabajo. Aunque se pueda encontrar en google, creo que es una buena pregunta y sería bueno que otros miembros de la comunidad puedan encontrar la respuesta aquí. Si conoces la respuesta por favor publícala para que otros puedan encontrala.

Comment: http://eidermauricio.blogspot.com.es/2007/06/controlando-el-teclado-extenido-en-c.html Respuesta dada por @Pikoh.

Comment: @AbrahamTS entiendo tus razones, pero debes entender que aqui se espera que haya un esfuerzo mínimo para encontrar solución a los problemas. Dado que todavía se está comenzando en [es.so] y todavía falta bastante información,te doy la razón que puede ser interesante, y por eso he añadido una respuesta,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A partir de la versión 2.0 del .Net Framework, para detectar el estado del Bloqueo de Mayusculas,Bloqueo de números y Bloqueo de desplazamiento se puede utilizar [`Control.IsKeyLocked`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked(VS.80).aspx) (Windows Forms):

```
Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.NumLock);
Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.Scroll);
```

---

Otra opción es usar el Api de windows, importando la función `GetKeyState`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);
```

Y puedes usarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
bool BloqDesp = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x91)) & 0xffff) != 0;     
bool BloqMay = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
bool BloqNum = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x90)) & 0xffff) != 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Si estás trabajando en Windows.Forms, puedes usar :

Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varias opciones.

La opción de .Net Framework:

```
Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock);
```

O la opción por llamadas a la API de Windows:

```
//Defines la llamada a la función
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern short GetKeyState(int keyCode);

//Y luego llamas a la función con el code de la tecla en este caso BloqCaps
bool mayusActivado = (((ushort)GetKeyState(0x14)) & 0xffff) != 0;
```